# Redesign output by removing left cell

Tags: java, itext

If you see the below table I have separated two cells one cell is added as a left cell(Name) and one more cell added as a table.

I have tried below code :

I am using the package as import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
    new FileOutputStream("C:/Temp/TableWidthAlignment.pdf"));

document.open(); 

//Main table
PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(2);
mainTable.setWidths(new int[] { 10,90 });

//cell one is Name cell
PdfPCell innerCellKeyName = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name", boldFont));
//innerCellKeyName.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
mainTable.addCell(innerCellKeyName);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3); 
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("header with colspan 3")); 
cell.setColspan(3); 
table.addCell(cell); 
table.addCell("1.1"); 
table.addCell("2.1"); 
table.addCell("3.1"); 
table.addCell("1.2"); 
table.addCell("2.2"); 
table.addCell("3.2"); 
table.addCell("4.1"); 
table.addCell("4.2"); 
table.addCell("4.3"); 

//cell two is as table
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(table);
mainTable.addCell(cell2);

document.add(mainTable);
```

Output is:

[image: Actual output what I got from above code]

Expected output is : Cross box need to be removed form box in the left cell.

[image: Expected output]

Comment: You know that you are using an old version of iText, that has been End Of Life since December 2009, 7 years ago?

Comment: Yeah that's true, This is the old application that's the reason we had to follow the old rules..

Comment: We're 7 years later now. Maybe it's time to upgrade. Using row span would be the way to go, but row span wasn't supported for `PdfPTable` in your obsolete version of iText.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I have done some thing below it's working perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried some thing to make work out of expected result

Solution:
I have copy pasted the same above table and made the left cell as no boarder.

```
             document.open(); 

             PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(2);
             mainTable.setWidths(new int[] { 10,90 });

             PdfPCell innerCellKeyName = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name", boldFont));
             //innerCellKeyName.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
             mainTable.addCell(innerCellKeyName);

             // step4 
             PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3); 
             PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("header with colspan 3")); 
             cell.setColspan(3); 
             table.addCell(cell); 
             table.addCell("1.1"); 
             table.addCell("2.1"); 
             table.addCell("3.1"); 
             table.addCell("1.2"); 
             table.addCell("2.2"); 
             table.addCell("3.2"); 
             table.addCell("4.1"); 
             table.addCell("4.2"); 
             table.addCell("4.3"); 



             PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(table);
             mainTable.addCell(cell2);
             document.add(mainTable); 


             PdfPTable mainTable2 = new PdfPTable(2);
             mainTable2.setWidths(new int[] { 10,90 });

             PdfPCell innerCellKeyName2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", boldFont));

             innerCellKeyName2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
             mainTable2.addCell(innerCellKeyName2);

             // step4 
             PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(3); 
             PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("header with colspan 3")); 
             cell3.setColspan(3); 
             table2.addCell(cell3); 
             table2.addCell("1.1"); 
             table2.addCell("2.1"); 
             table2.addCell("3.1"); 
             table2.addCell("1.2"); 
             table2.addCell("2.2"); 
             table2.addCell("3.2"); 
             table2.addCell("4.1"); 
             table2.addCell("4.2"); 
             table2.addCell("4.3"); 



             PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(table2);
             mainTable2.addCell(cell4);


             document.add(mainTable2);
```